# Map API Text Searching for business_status = OPERATIONAL

Tags: python, google-maps

I am curious that if there is any method to limit the search result. So that we can find the place only with `business status = OPERATIONAL` or `business status != CLOSED_TEMPORARILY and CLOSED_PERMANENTLY`. I try to add the `$business_status=OPERATIONAL` into my searching URL but nothing change. There are still many `CLOSED_TEMPORATILY` places in my `JSON` result. Can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Instead of capitalizing words in a paragraph, I'd suggest adding them as formatted code. As a side note, it looks like `Enum` could likely help out here.